# Sum of GCD(k,n)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, divisibility

I want to find this

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \gcd(k,n)$$

but I don't know how to solve. Does anybody can help me to finding this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how many integers $k$ in the range $1 \leq k \leq n$ are relatively prime to $n$ so that $\gcd(k,n) = 1$? (Hint: Read about _Euler's totient function_.)

Comment: n $\leq$ 200000. Ok I will read Euler's totient function.

Comment: Useful paper: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL4/BROUGHAN/gcdsum.pdf Simple explanation: https://forthright48.com/gcd-sum-function

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is Pillai's arithmetical function as in [OEIS A018804](http://oeis.org/A018804)

Formulae given there include $$\sum_{d|n} d \,\phi(n/d)$$ and $$\sum_{d|n} d \, \tau(d) \, \mu(n/d)$$ where $\phi(n)$ is [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), $\tau(n)$ is the [number of divisors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) and $\mu(n)$ is the [Möbius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).