# Sum of reciprocal GCDs

Tags: number-theory, summation, gcd-and-lcm

Is there a closed form expression for this for $n\in\mathbb N$?

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\gcd(k,n)}$$

Comment: Do you want something more than $n\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)/d$?

Comment: Yes if possible.

Comment: See [OEIS A057660](https://oeis.org/A057660).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135351/sum-of-gcdk-n

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Any idea to compute that sequence very fast? (For $n\le 10^7$).

Comment: This is a problem from the [Code Chef November Challenge](http://www.codechef.com/NOV15/problems/SMPLSUM/), according to our contest policy, the question will be locked until the contest is over.

Comment: The formula given by Paolo Leonetty is faulty. The correct formula is $(1/n)\sum_{d\mid n}d\,\varphi(d)$.